# Juntar tabela fotos à consulta

Tags: php, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta que pega os favoritos do utilizador `ID=X`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT user_2_id FROM favoritos WHERE
user_1_id =$id_user_logado)";
```

Agora, como eu posso pegar a foto de utilizador dos utilizador que saem dessa consulta? O `id` da foto é guardado na tabela do utilizador no campo `photo_p_id` e a informação relativa à foto está na tabela `photos` como a localização da mesma.

Algo deste gênero:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN 
(SELECT user_2_id FROM favoritos WHERE
user_1_id =$id_user_logado)

LEFT JOIN photos AS p

ON user.photo_p_id=p.id     

";
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi desta forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT  u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao,    u.status,u.last_login, u.photo_p_id, p.location, f.user_2_id, f.user_1_id

FROM user AS u 

LEFT JOIN photos AS p

ON u.photo_p_id=p.id 

LEFT JOIN favoritos AS f

ON f.user_2_id=u.id 

WHERE f.user_1_id =$id_user_logado

LIMIT 5;
";
```